# PHP, OOP, Static

Tags: php, oop, static

I am studying PHP,OOP and i am at Static,
At this [php.net/static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) i didnt understand this sentence

```
Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.
```

I did understand it's Valid for methods only (not for Properties) by the sentence above,
but i didn't succeed to understand It practically,
I'm glad if anything could please show me code that explains the sentence above,
Wishing you a pleasant week.

Comment: It tells you that if you call a non-static method without initialize it, i gives a E_STRICT warning. What you don't understand exactly? Static means that you can call the method without initialize the class as an object.

Comment: The most important thing you should learn about OOP and static calls is that they do not mix. Static call are part of procedural programming mindset.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers i am reading them right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo
{
    public static $my_static = 'foo';
    public $my_non_static = 'bar';

    public function staticValue() {
        return self::$my_static;
    }

    public function nonStaticValue() {
        return self::$my_non_static;
    }
}

print Foo::$my_static . "\n"; // OK
print Foo::staticValue(). "\n"; // E_STRICT

print Foo::$my_non_static . "\n"; // Fatal
print Foo::nonStaticValue(). "\n"; // Fatal
```

`print Foo::$my_static . "\n";` is OK - static property accessed statically.

`print Foo::staticValue(). "\n";` gives E_STRICT - non-static method accessed statically, but not Fatal error, because this method doesn't access non-static properties.

Other two give Fatal error because non-static field cannot be accessed statically.

Comment: When you saying non-static field you Mean that the value is not define as a static value that inside a static field? and about the E_STRICT it's not only becouse it's access non-static properies i can return simple string i dont have to self:$x_static_prop.

Comment: When I'm saying non-static field I mean property, defined without static keyword. Sorry, I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: Thank you Ruben, i understand you now, and about my second sentence i meant that i can do return 'Hellow'; and not self::$static_prop.

Comment: So it's not only "because this method doesn't access non-static properties" can you explain in other words please...

Comment: I mean if method accesses non-static properties, it can be accessed only non-statically (through an instance). 'Hellow' is not non-static property, it is just constant value. So you can use it in static method.

Comment: I Understand it all now, thank you Very much Ruben for you help and Have a Nice Day.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of what they mean with the sentence you are asking about.

Consider the following class with one method (it is not static).

```
class Test
{
    function method()
    {
        echo "Hello from method";
    }
}

Test::method();  // attempt to statically call a non-static method
```

This is the output:

> **Strict Standards**: Non-static method Test::method() should not be
>   called statically in /obj.php on line 12
>   Hello from method

As you can see, it *did* execute the method when called static even though it is not a static method, however a strict error message was displayed.

If the method `method()` referenced the keyword `$this`, then you would encounter a fatal error because `$this` does not exist in the context of a static method call.  So while it is technically possible to call a non-static class method statically, it should not be done.

EDIT:

The reason you are even allowed to call a non-static class member statically is because the static keyword did not exist in PHP4 in the context of class methods so if you were designing a static class or method in PHP4, there was no keyword to indicate it, you would simply call it in the static fashion.  Now PHP5 emits the warning if the method is called statically but doesn't have the static keyword in the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

It's because even if you can call non-static methods statically, you shouldn't and it will be logged.

```
class Foo {
    function bar(){
        print "you should not do that";
    }
}
```

`Foo::bar();` would actually works, but you will get a **E_STRICT** warning because you **can** do that,  but you **shouln't**.

Comment: Thank You, your last line Really clarified things.

Answer (score 0):

If a method is non-static, it means that it belongs to an instance of a class. For example, if we have a class `Car` with a method called `getDamage()` (which computes how much damaged the car is), then you should not call this method in a static way.

You should only create an instance of the `Car` class and call `getDamage()` on that instance. This makes sense because a particular car can be damaged for 25% while another car can be damaged for 70%.

But calling `getDamage()` in a static way makes no sense: a static method does not belong to a particular instance of the class but to the class itself. And a `Car` class has no useful way of giving a result for `getDamage()`. You could still compute a value (perhaps `0`) but it does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Very Good Logical one.